# what is the value of x in the concave polygon below?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

I know that the value of $x$ in this problem is 169 by exterior angle sum theorem (I extended the dashed line with the 58° angle to create a triangle). But I have to fill in this equation to solve for $x$. I just don't know how to come with that equation.

$x-(...)+(...)+(...)=(...)$

[image]

Comment: Try to use the fact that the sum of the angles inside the quadrilateral is 360º.

Comment: What is your difficulty?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I'm having a difficulty figuring out the missing numbers in the equation. I know that the concave polygon is quadrilateral so its interior angle sum is 360. But that doesn't seem help me figure them out.

Comment: If you don't know that one of the interior angles equals $58^{\circ}+180^{\circ}$, you can't know what $\angle{X}$ equals.

Answer (score 1):

Trace the polygon going anti-clockwise. The sum of the angles through which you turn to get back to your starting point and starting direction should be $360^{\circ}$. Where you turn **anti-clockwise** the angles are **positive**. Where you turn **clockwise** from one side to the next these angles are **negative**.

Starting at the top left vertex and heading approx. south :
$$(+x)+(-58)+(+158)+(+91)=360$$

Comment: I still don't understand how you got the $x-58$.

Comment: I am adding the angles through which you turn as you move around the polygon. $x$ is +ve because you turn anticlockwise. $58$ is -ve because you turn clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the red line as shown.

[image]

By 'exterior angle of triangle', x = p + q = (r + s) + q

Start replacing q, r , and s by suitable numbers.

Re-arrange terms to make an equation that has the required form.